# File Dialog Throws a Null Reference When Cancelled

Tags: c#, silverlight

In my site that has a file upload function, the File Dialog returns a null reference when I don't select a file and click Cancel. But here's the catch:

When the user:

1. Open file dialog > select file > click Open, but thought maybe he selected the wrong file, so he -- > open file dialog > click Cancel, the file uploads successfully. But...
2. On that same page, there's a button that allows you to edit the entry you just created. So maybe the user uploaded the wrong file, so he -- open file dialog > select file > click Open, but again thought maybe he selected the wrong file so he -- openfile dialog > click Cancel. The fun ends here as I get an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error.

What confuses me is that it goes through the same code but the first time it's run it works and on the second it fails?

BTW, I'm using Michiel Post's [MultiFileUpload](http://www.michielpost.nl/Silverlight/MultiFileUploader/) project.

The scenarios I've given runs through this code:

```
else
        {
            MultiFileUpload.SelectUserFiles();  //This calls the MultiFileUpload            

            if (MultiFileUpload.UserFiles.FileList.LastOrDefault().FileName != refFileName)
            {
                //do something
            }

            else
            {
                //this is triggered when the user clicks Cancel on the FileDialog
                return; 
            }
        }
```

Again, the code works for scenario number 1, but fails for scenario number 2 which obviously is just the same as 1.

Comment: There is no way we can help you without seeing some code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your code in

```
try{

}
catch(Exception ex){
  // Show message here
}
```

Or you should make a filter for File Dialog.